# Reference for multicriteria optimisation

Tags: reference-request, optimization

I am taking a course on multicriteria optimisation and the textbook being used by the professor for the course is the book by [Ehrgott](https://www.amazon.de/Multicriteria-Optimization-Matthias-Ehrgott/dp/3642059759)

 However, i find the text has few examples and is pretty low on motivation. The topics which will be covered in the course are: Pareto optimality, non dominance, weighted sum method and scalarization, multiobjective simplex and cobinatorial methods.

Can anyone please recommend a book on multicriteria optimisation which has examples and/or motivates the arguments behind the theory. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now in a stage to answer my own question. The following books helped me in the study of Multicriteria Optimisation over the past year:

1. [Ehrgott - MulticriteriaOptimization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540213988) is actually a good introduction to the topic. It covers all the essentials: weighted sum, $\epsilon$-constraint, multi criteria simplex etc.
2. [Cohon - Multiobjective Programming and Planning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A735M9Y) is also very good but as the title suggests, the viewpoint is towards decision making and it is also not upto date.
3. [Sawaragi - Theory of Multiobjective optimization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0089NV29S) is a good reference for the theory of multi criteria optimisation. Some of the proofs that cannot be found in Ehrgott's book can be found here.